# cannot give value to struck array/variable in a loop

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, struct

I am trying to give coordinates to polygon. `arrayx` and `arrayy` are the arrays which contain my x and y coordinates. The problem is, I cannot give the values of my arrays to `polygon` Point structure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

struct Point
{
    int x,y;
};

int main()
{    

  Point polygon[]={};
  int n=0, arrayx[1024] = {0} , arrayy[1024] = {0};

   //input
   ifstream iFile;
   iFile.open("in.txt");

        while(iFile >> arrayx[n] >> arrayy[n])
        {

            n = n + 1;
        }

    iFile.close(); 

    int k=n;          
    for (int j=0; j<= k; j++)
    {
        polygon[j] = (Point){arrayx[j],arrayy[j]}; //something wrong here

        //output
        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open ("out3.txt", ios::app);
        myfile  <<"k = " <<k << "----" <<j << ") polygon.x = "<< polygon[j].x  <<" arrayx = "<<arrayx[j] << " polygon[j].y = "<< polygon[j].y  <<" arrayy = "<<arrayy[j] << "\n";
        myfile.close();
    }
}
```

I also tried change  code like below:

```
polygon[j].x = arrayx[j];
polygon[j].y = arrayy[j];
```

Input:

```
260 673
565 735
780 619
746 408
333 400
```

Output:

```
k = 260 
j = 673    
polygon[j].x = 7209071     
arrayx = 0 
polygon[j].y = 7471220 
arrayy = 0
```

Suddenly `k` changes its value to 260. variable of loop `j` goes to 673, (not j=0,1,2,3,4,5 only one time loping and breaks) even `arrays[673]` are empty, `polygon` gets some numbers.

I do not have much experience about c++, it is hard to me solve it by alone.

Comment: please provide the code where you are declaring `polygon`

Comment: Your posted code has no IO whatsoever, so we have no idea how that output is being produced *at all*. And add the declarations of `arrayx` and `arrayy` to the missing-persons list. If all three are arrays `[5]` then your loop is exceeding the boundary declarations due to `j <= k` in the for-conditional rather than `j < k`.

Comment: You'll need to provide a full working example. Why are arrayx and arrayy 0? Are they pointers that haven't been given an allocation yet? That would be a big problem.

Comment: It still isn't right. You still haven't included the declarations of any of the vars requested in the first two comments. The list of things missing to make this a [**Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is still non-trivial, including `int main {` isn't even valid C++. Regardless, your for-loop is wrong. It should be `j < n`, not `j <= k`, and depending on the declarations of `polygons`, `arrayx`, and `arrayy` that continue to elude us, the upper `while` loop is likely also wrong.

Comment: polygon, arrayx and arrayy are not declared anywhere. Please provide code that will compile.

Comment: I have changed, please look again. If you will have any question, please inform me

Comment: @isifzade Did you consider to inspect your code stepping through line by line with a debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not going to be able to assign anything to the array as the array is empty

```
Point polygon[]={};
```

This should be causing a compiler error as 0 sized arrays are not allowed in standard C++.